# Warning while running ensemble code in R

Tags: r, if-statement, ensemble-learning

I am trying to run an ensemble model using the majority vote method. this is the code for it.

```
pred_majority<-as.factor(ifelse(pred_rf_new=='TRUE' & 
model_1_epoch_predict$predict=='TRUE','TRUE',ifelse(pred_rf_new=='TRUE' & ksvm_predict=='TRUE','TRUE',ifelse(model_1_epoch_predict$predict=='TRUE' & ksvm_predict=='TRUE','TRUE','FALSE'))))
```

Executing the line reverts the following warning.

```
Warning messages:
1: In pred_rf_new == "TRUE" & model_1_epoch_predict$predict == "TRUE" :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In model_1_epoch_predict$predict == "TRUE" & ksvm_predict == "TRUE" :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Did you look at `length(pred_rf_new)` and `length(model_1_epoch_predict$predict)` ?

Comment: @G5W yes I did, they are all 999